# Setting custom connection timeout in retrofit not working

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

retrofit not taking custom timeout, it takes default 10 sec for connection timeout.

I have already tried all the methods setting custom timeout like the below code.

```
//service generator class
    public class ServiceGenerator{

    private Context context;

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =new OkHttpClient.Builder();

     private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
                    new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(UriList.BASE_URL)
                            .client(getRequestHeader())
                          .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static HttpLoggingInterceptor setLogger() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        return logging;
    }


    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, Context context) {

        if (!httpClient.interceptors().isEmpty()) {

            httpClient.interceptors().clear();
        }


            httpClient.addInterceptor(new NetworkConnectionInterceptor(context));
            httpClient.addInterceptor(setLogger());
            httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();
                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
    MyApplication.getInstance().getApiCredential())
                            .header("LocalSystemDate", MyApplication.getInstance().getCurrentDateAndTimeWithTimeZone())
                            .method(original.method(), original.body());
                    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            });

        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }


    private static OkHttpClient getRequestHeader() {

        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();
    }


}
```

After 10 sec i get error :

```
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

Comment: can you add your calling method?

Comment: @RajasekaranM calling method: Service service = ServiceGenerator.createService(Service.class, context);
        Call<List<UserModel1>> opSearchResults = service.getOpSearchResults();

Comment: can you update ServiceGenerator full code?

Comment: @RajasekaranM hi,i have updated full code

Comment: i have fixed this issue by calling connect timeout inside create service class :)    .....   httpClient.addInterceptor(new NetworkConnectionInterceptor(context));
        httpClient.addInterceptor(setLogger());
        httpClient.connectTimeout(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        httpClient.readTimeout(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        httpClient.writeTimeout(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() ....

Comment: you are not using correct httpclient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are used wrong httpclient when create retrofit object

You have to add below lines of codes inside `createService(Class<S> serviceClass, Context context)`

```
 httpClient.readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
           .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
           .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

So your `createService(Class<S> serviceClass, Context context)` would be

```
public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, Context context) {

            if (!httpClient.interceptors().isEmpty()) {

                httpClient.interceptors().clear();
            }


            httpClient.addInterceptor(new NetworkConnectionInterceptor(context));
            httpClient.addInterceptor(setLogger());
            httpClient.readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();
                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    MyApplication.getInstance().getApiCredential())
                            .header("LocalSystemDate", MyApplication.getInstance().getCurrentDateAndTimeWithTimeZone())
                            .method(original.method(), original.body());
                    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            });

            OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
            Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
            return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
        }
```

It's will work now. try it .